# How do I enable TODO/FIXME/XXX task tags in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tags, task

In all my years of using Eclipse, I never knew until now that TODO / FIXME / XXX comment tags are supposed to appear in the task list. Apparently this is something that is disabled by default because I have been using those tags for as long as I've been using Eclipse and I have never seen one of them appear in the task list. Can anyone indicate how to enable this feature? I see no preferences option anywhere that says anything to the effect of 'Let my source code tags appear in the task list'. It would be a nice feature if it existed, but I'm beginning to be doubtful.

I have asked around, and as others have suggested to me, these are some things which obviously have no effect but that I have tried anyway:

- Upgrading to the latest version of Eclipse.
- Restarting Eclipse.
- Closing and re-opening the task list.
- Refreshing the project.

I am using:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Helios Service Release 1
Build id: 20100917-0705

Comment: _Tasks_ view and _Task List_ view in Eclipse are not the same.

Answer (score 136):

For me, such tags are enabled by default. You can configure which task tags should be used in the workspace options: **Java > Compiler > Task tags**

[image]

Check if they are enabled in this location, and that should be enough to have them appear in the Task list (or the Markers view).

Extra note: reinstalling Eclipse won't change anything most of the time if you work on the same workspace. Most settings used by Eclipse are stored in the .metadata folder, in your workspace folder.

Comment: Oh, wait, I now have a Tasks window on the bottom of the screen that displays the tasks. However, initially I was looking at the Task List window on the side of the screen.

Comment: @Jeff - the task list is something different, it's for tracking issues, when you connect to such a tracking server, not for the tags in code. I recommend you configure the Markers view, to have errors/warnings/TODOS on the same place (for example limiting warnings to the open file)

Comment: @Gnoupi - thanks for helping clear up the confusion! I finally understood and started converting a Markers: Java Task - TODO into a Mylin Task (which is open by default in the Java Perspective) and then I caught myself, remembering your advice above--slapped my head-- and replaced the Mylin/Task List view with the General/Markers view.

Comment: Any way to limit the // TODOs listed in Tasks to just the ones from your current project?

Comment: Or any way to limit the listed TODOs to certain packages?

Comment: @SnowCrash - I'd recommend toying with the Markers view, to limit to the same project, or to a working set. Else, you can also write "//TODO projectname" everytime (maybe use a template), and have a separate markers view for different kinds of TODOs.

Comment: @OskarBirkne - Define a working set on those packages, and use a markers view filtered on this working set.

Comment: @Gnoupi I'm not sure what you mean by "Markers view". I'd assume this would be under Window > Show View > Markers. However I don't see it.

Comment: @SnowCrash - that's the one. You can limit one to "Java task" (or another kind of task), and filter it over a working set.

Answer (score 39):

In the distribution I use, the tasks are listed in the task list by default (at least for Java). For other content types, you may check the following settings.

Display the Tasks View:
Window > Show View > Other > General > Tasks

For non-Java Task Tags: check the following settings:
Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Structured Text Editors > Task Tags
You can enable searching for task tags in the [Task Tags] tab and select the content types in the [Filters] tab.

For Java task tags, you should look in:
Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Task Tags

J.

Comment: "Display the Tasks View: Window > Show View > Other > General > Tasks": I don't have this. I have Show View > Other, but then there's no General option. Nonetheless I believe I have found the Tasks option. It is not the same as the Task List option, which is what I have been looking at the whole time.

Comment: this one is the one that works with other source code files. For instance, .scala files.

Comment: Worked with my Php perspective

Answer (score 20):

I'm using Eclipse Classic 3.7.1.

The solution is: Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Sctructured Text Editors > Task Tags and checking "Enable searching for Task Tags" checkbox.

Comment: this one is the one that works with other source code files. For instance, .scala files.

Answer (score 9):

All those settings are necessary to choose which tags you are interested in, but in order to display these tags in a list, you also need to select the right Eclipse perspective. I finally discovered that the "Markers" tab containing the "Task" list is only available under the "Java EE" perspective... Hope this helps! :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are apparently distributions or custom builds in which the ability to set Task Tags for non-Java files is not present. [This post](http://www.iterateme.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/3/3/Simple-But-Super-Useful-CFBuilder-2-Enhancement-Task-and-TODO-Support) mentions that ColdFusion Builder (built on Eclipse) does not let you set non-Java Task Tags, but the beta version of CF Builder 2 does. (I know the OP wasn't using CF Builder, but I am, and I was wondering about this question myself ... because he didn't see the ability to set non-Java tags, I thought others might be in the same position.)