# Eclipse does not show TODO tasks

Tags: java, eclipse

After upgrading to Eclipse Juno and importing an existing Java EE project, the Tasks view does not show TODOs from comments in my .java files. I can manually add new TODO tasks by specifically right-clicking the gutter and selecting `Add Task...` from the popup menu, but Eclipse should create TODOs from my comments on its own.

I went through all the preferences related to task tags, they are all default (thus OK), still no tags appear. I tried closing/opening the project, re-building it, I checked Git repo to see that no dot files (.project etc) were modified since everything worked in the older Eclipse.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388292/how-do-i-enable-todo-fixme-xxx-task-tags-in-eclipse) question did not help me... how to make Eclipse show my Java TODOs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I investigated my `.project` file and found the following natures:

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.ajnature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
</natures>
```

The first one refers to AspectJ that I use to process some annotations. I realized that the newly installed Eclipse does not contain AspectJ tools by default! After installing AJDT, my TODOs appeared in the Tasks view, thus solving the problem.

Weird thing is, why does not Eclipse complain about having a project with an unknown nature (=one there is no plugin for)? And why did this absence of AJDT cause the regular JDT to fail finding the TODOs?..

Comment: Thx! Same problem after upgrading to eclipse luna.  I did a "Install New Software" from http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/44/dev/update/ and it works now! ;)

Answer (score 21):

The problem is Eclipse should rebuild the settings (probably a bug). The way to work around this is to start **Windows > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Task Tags**, then change any tag, then press apply; you will be asked if you allow settings to rebuild, accept.
Then change back the altered tag and rebuild again. You should have immediately shown TODO in the Tasks view.

Comment: This helped me. I would also add that this worked for PHP projects too. Seems like editing the Preferences > PHP > Editor > Task tags doesn't rebuild the tasks. But editing the Java > Compiler > Task Tags menu does force the rebuild for all langs.

Comment: After upgrading to Eclipse Luna, I was having the same problem with an existing project that I imported into my new workspace. It didn't show any tags, even when the project had many. Building the project (ctrl+b) worked for me

Comment: The project rebuild is the essential part of this workaround within my current Eclipse installation, too. Sadly, it needs to be performed after every added TODO to make it visible. Removing TODOs on the other hand is reflected immediately.

Comment: you can also.. just `Right click` on your project then click `Build Project`

Answer (score 5):

In my case I was just not aware of the fact that the project has to build correctly in order for the TODOs to show up.
After I fixed the build errors there was no problem anymore to see the TODOs.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to enable **Project** -> **Build Automatically**. Then trigger an auto-build by adding, removing or modifying a resource.