# What's is the best practice for marking variables that you need to delete later in Java?

Tags: java

I scratched my head for two weeks trying to compute something based a variable.

It turns out I set the variable earlier to solve temporarily another problem and never went back to correct it.

Normally, I try to mark up code with //ToDo 's to remind me to remove the temporary variable.

In this case, I didn't mark it since I was skipping around trying to fix more than a few things. (I couldn't figure out what was going on so I was trying all sorts of stuff!)

How do you mark temporary variables that you wish to remove later?

1. Do you instantiate them as private at the top of the class?
2. Mark them inline with something like //Delete Me Later

What's is the best practice for marking variables that you need to delete later?

(short of having a really organized brain of course...)

Comment: In C# we have an attribute for it:
[Obsolete("Use MethodB instead")]

So it does make me think Java should have something similair though.

Comment: In my experience *fix me later* is often equivalent to *never fix*, so the boring answer would be to fix it now.

Comment: @Johan, sometimes you still want to keep the old method for a few more versions, as external programs that use the library for example, will break when they update, this will lead to angry customers. By marking it "Obsolete" or "Deprecated", they have time to fix it and still can update to take advantages of other bug fixes for example.

Comment: @MrMichael, absolutely. Hypothetically, what situation is so dire that it requires *introducing* a **varible** that *needs* to go, and which cannot be performed by e.g., a `@Deprecated` method instead?

Comment: You shouldn't have methods so long that you can't see it all at once (or within a page scroll). The problem you had is but one reason (symptomatic of not being able to hold the whole method in mind at once).

Comment: @OrangeDog Not sure about that one. Some folks (like me) load up a class first to make something work and then clean it up.

Comment: @JackfromBlisd indeed, and then you end up wasting two weeks because of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of commenting to every single idea / recommendation, I thought I would answer and then have you vote on this answer.

First, thank you very much for sharing your processes and ideas. I really appreciate it.

I think there are a number of factors in play that should be driven by the desire to avoid making stupid mistakes or suffering from ones you have already made. I made one (of many.)

Let's just assume that version control and team reviews trump all; however beyond version control (assuming that you committed crappola to your good code):

- @Deprecated is very good. It seems to glare at you. We all need glaring. Hopefully we can see the forest through the trees.
- To me, diffs are onerous since I frequently make sweeping changes but it is a great suggestion that works in many cases.

Some notable things:

Since I am usually sole developer, I rely on ToDos. They're easy to use.  I have an informal rating system with the todos. For example, something that really needs to be cleaned up looks like this:

```
//TODO * Might be a future crash here // where one star is something I really have to clean up before I ship. 
//TODO *** Can some lines be trimmed from this view adapter?
```

Multiple stars are arbitrary and perhaps even optional. I keep cycling through them. @BriGuy37 - that was an interesting thought. @Sriram - that was interesting too - setting up tags under certain conditions.

In my case, I didn't dox the //TODO and it burned me.

Biggest rule perhaps out of all of this is:

Unitize your work in a manner that you don't make stupid errors like this. Know what changes you're making and when. Keep calm.

Thanks again! It's great to pick up best practices from the community to incorporate in your work!

Answer (score 36):

Use the annotation `@Deprecated`

```
@Deprecated
public void Test() {
  //
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Found it after a bit of googling, as i was curious also.

```
@Deprecated
public void speak() {
   System.out.println("Meow."); 
}
```

From Wikipedia, on [Java annotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotations):

> Java defines a set of annotations which are built into the
>   language.  Annotations applied to java code: @Override - Checks
>   that the function is an override. Causes a compile warning if the
>   function is not found in one of the parent classes. @Deprecated -
>   Marks the function as obsolete. Causes a compile warning if the
>   function is used. @SuppressWarnings - Instructs the compiler to
>   suppress the compile time warnings specified in the annotation
>   parameters   Annotations applied to other annotations: @Retention -
>   Specifies how the marked annotation is stored—Whether in code only,
>   compiled into the class, or available at runtime through reflection.
>   @Documented - Marks another annotation for inclusion in the
>   documentation. @Target - Marks another annotation to restrict what
>   kind of java elements the annotation may be applied to @Inherited -
>   Marks another annotation to be inherited to subclasses of annotated
>   class (by default annotations are not inherited to subclasses).

Answer (score 5):

The best practice is to use version control. Once you've fixed a bug, you can git/hg/svn diff to check what you've done since last commit and remove any temporary changes. If you need to fix other bugs, but keep the "temporary change" over several commits, you can do partial commits (git add --patch, or hg qrecord) so your "temporary changes" never gets committed and forgotten. For very large temporaries (not best practice, but it may happen), you can create a local branch which you keep rebasing over the normal code. Once you're sure to remove the "temporary changes", you can simply clean up any uncommitted changes and then test for issues.

Answer (score 4):

Local branches (git, shelving changes in IntelliJ, two copies of the source checked out locally), so when you are moved from one task to another, rather than just working over the part-way-completed work you create a second branch and don't commit/push the first until it has been completed.

Pair commits/pushes - so you don't commit until you have talked the code over with a second person, who will point at the temporary chunk of code and ask you about it. Hopefully forcing you to fix the damn issue before committing it.

Don't use TODOs or other such comments as they will neverbe actioned on.

If it is already public and is being used externally then @Deprecate it.

Answer (score 0):

First, I preface each variable name with "TODO_REMOVE_" or something similar.  That way, if I forget to remove it and someone comes across it later, it is clear that the variable should be removed.  Also, if I perform the last step below, I will ALWAYS remove it before I check it in.

Next, I add a TODO comment to it and annotate it with Deprecated.  I know others have said that TODOs are never actioned on, but when I make a commit, my IDE (IntelliJ in this case) warns me that there are X TODOs being committed.  If you get a similar message when you checkin, that should throw a flag up in your mind.  Also, if you find yourself doing this often, make a live template, snippet, or whatever else your IDE affords so you only have to type the class type and variable name.

```
@Deprecated
Object TODO_REMOVE_variableName;//TODO Remove
```

Last, I seek to re-read, understand, improve, and confirm EVERY line of code that I write before I check a change set in.  This is CRUCIAL!  I know it may sound daunting at first, especially for large changes or when you have a looming deadline, but it is a drop in the bucket next to the time it took you to write the code, and the issues it reveals and the future time it saves are well worth it.  Truly, I wish every developer did this.

Comment: +1 for just reading diffs before checking in.  I find that this is a case where code reviews really help -- I usually check the diff before I send it out for review, and again after, and it's prevented me from checking in temporary changes (or even simply unnecessary changes) too many times to count.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, I would suggest you to

Have a new task tag, say 'REMOVE', which could help you to easily identify what temporary code needs to be removed. Set priority to High.

Open the tasks view to check for REMOVE tasks and take action.

Please go through below link(a UI screenshot is provided too)

[StackOverflow Q/A on Task tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388292/how-do-i-enable-todo-fixme-xxx-task-tags-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SVN* and the change you're making is something that should be fixed before your changes are committed (e.g. a temporary change for debugging/testing locally) you can add a comment like `// STOP-COMMIT` and set up a pre-commit hook that prohibits committing any file containing this text.

This also works well for marking local changes to configuration files that should not be committed to SVN.

If your IDE supports a TODO list that searching comments for a given string you can even create a custom TODO format looking for this string.

* I would guess you can do something similar with many other version control systems