# Make Task Tags Bold in Editor

Tags: eclipse, settings, eclipse-pdt

In one build of eclipse (it is on a computer I no longer have access to), when I typed in a task tag like `//TODO` or `//FIXME` eclipse would bold this in the editor so it stood out. How can I turn this functionality on in Eclipse 4.2.2 with PDT?

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388292/how-do-i-enable-todo-fixme-xxx-task-tags-in-eclipse)

Comment: I meant.. there is a similar question asked.. and answer was shown.. so i thought duplicate post...

Comment: I know what you meant, but I couldn't find another question concerning task tags on Stackoverflow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388292/how-do-i-enable-todo-fixme-xxx-task-tags-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the setting for this under Window-Preferences-PHP-Editor-Syntax Coloring. Strangely, I had to change the PHPDoc option, not the Task Tag option.